# How can I recolor non editable area of a swing table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

so I've just created a table using swing Table and everything went well but I always have a greyed out area that I want to recolor (247,247,247 instead of the standard grey)

The table will be dynamic, so it extends if needed (if this information is needed).

Is there any option to change it?

This is a example that I found: 
https://github.com/k33ptoo/SwingInspire/blob/master/images/sc.png

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please complete your question with a [mre], a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org) or at least show us what you've tried or researched so far. If you haven't yet, check out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), a guide on asking questions on Stack Overflow efficiently so that you will receive better help sooner!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own TableCellRenderer. You can do this by creating a subclass of DefaultTableCellRenderer

```
class MyClass extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(...);
    if (row == ... && column == ...) {
      comp.setBackground(...);
    }
    return comp;
  }

}
```

Comment: FYI: `JTable` has no method `setTableCellRenderer`. `JTable` has either possibility to set a default renderer for a class (`table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new MyRenderer())`) or possibility to set a renderer for a column (via column model).